# Detecting change source (user or program) in radio buttons

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, radio-button

I'm trying to set a flag saying whether the last change on the `Checked` property was caused by the user or the program.

I'm using a custom `RadioButton`:

```
public class MyRadioButton : RadioButton
{
    ValueChanger valueChanger = ValueChanger.Program;

    public MyRadioButton()
    {
        this.Click += OnButtonClickedByUser;
        this.CheckedChanged += OnCheckChange;
    }

    public void setChecked(bool val)
    {
        this.valueChanger = ValueChanger.Program;
        this.Checked = val;
    }

    void OnButtonClickedByUser(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.valueChanger = ValueChanger.User;
    }

    void OnCheckChange(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // do stuff depending on 'this.valueChanger'
    }


    enum ValueChanger
    {
        User,
        Program
    };
}
```

I call `setChecked` whenever the value was changed because of a message received from a serial connection, and I expect `OnButtonClickedByUser` to be called by the `Click` event whenever the value is changed through the UI.

My problem is that the `CheckedChanged` event fires before the `Click` event, which makes `OnCheckChange` unreliable.

Is there any way to fix that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User can change the value of the `RadioButton` by click on the control or by moving the focus to the control (arrow key, tab, mnemonic key combination).

Both `OnEnter` and `ProcessMnemonic` try to call `PerformClick` which calls `OnClick` which is responsible to checking the control. So you can override `OnClick` method:

```
protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e) 
{
    // Here CheckedChanged event has not been raised yet

    base.OnClick(e);
}
```

To find out more about how `RadioButton` works internally, take a look at its [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/RadioButton.cs,d0b89209dce765e1).

Comment: To me it seems to be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Anyway, I shared the answer, you may find it useful.

Comment: The XY Problem part is interesting and definitely relevant. I should've asked about other methods in addition to fixing the solution I attempted.

Comment: The question in the current format is good enough. By saying about *XY* problem I just shared my guess and curiosity about *X*. If for any reason you like to ask question about *X*, it's better to ask in another thread :)